# Problems with D-Link USB Wifi-adapter

Tags: wireless, networking

I am currently using a network cable to connect to my router. I have a wireless router but my desktop doesn't have wireless connection (WiFi). So I have to use a WiFi adapter. I use a USB type of adapter. But when I plug it in the LED doesn't come on and it appears dead. But it works in Windows.

So what do I have to do to make a WiFi connection to my router?

**Update:**

Output of lsusb command.

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 07d1:3a09 D-Link System DWA-160 802.11abgn Xtreme N Dual Band Adapter(rev.A2) [Atheros AR9170+AR9104]
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Plug your device, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `lsusb`, then post its output.

Comment: Why does it say LX710? The keyboard is an MX3200 by Logitech. Does it matter? I am a complete noob when it comes to Linux. I just installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tested 8.04 LTS a few years ago and back then I also had to use a network cable because I couldn't get the WiFi adapter to work. It was the same adapter - a d-link dwa160 revision a2. Is this thing supported now in Ubuntu?

Comment: It says "atheros". Is that good? Is that the chipset? I remember that there was a discussion regarding revision b and a and as I recall the revision b was the Atheros model. If remember correctly this was supposed to be used with Ralink drivers. But I have the older a2 revision and yet it says it's "atheros"? Is this correct?... if so, why is it not working out of the box? And do I have to install the Ralink driver manually?

Comment: You needn't install Ralink drivers for your Atheros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your device 07d1:3a09 works with the driver carl9170. It also requires firmware which should be installed by default. Check:

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep carl
```

You should find carl9170-1.fw and carl9170fw. If not, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Now unload and reload the module:

```
sudo modprobe -r carl9170 && sudo modprobe carl9170
```

Was a wireless interface, ideally wlan0, created?

```
iwconfig
```

Does it scan and connect?

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

If not, look for other problems in the message logs:

```
dmesg | grep carl
rfkill list all
```

Comment: It appeared under Network (System Settings, Network) but there were no network names or any other details that would suggest that it was connected. I rebooted and after some time I was able to pick a network name from the drop down list. So it works now.

Comment: Output of `ls /lib/firmware | grep carl`: carl9170-1.fw Is this good? I don't have that other dude, the "carl9170fw". Is that cool? I don't need both?

Comment: By the way, the LED is flashing like every 30 second when I am not surfing the web or downloading something. Is that normal? It might explain why I didn't see it flash. I would have had to stare at it for some time to notice it. Because in Windows the LED flashes like crazy all the time, whether I use the network or not. Also, when I am viewing Network in Ubuntu the LED stays lit all the time. What's up with that?

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.